# How to solve the following integral equation?

Tags: integral-equations

$g(s) = \frac{\lambda A}{1-e^{-\lambda T}}s$ for $s\in [0, T]$.

$g(s) = \int_{0}^{T} \lambda e^{-\lambda t} g(s-t) dt + A$. for $s \ge T$.

$T, A, \lambda$ are constant. I want to get the closed-form of $g$ for $s > T$.

Comment: Solving for what ? What is known ? What is unknown ?

Comment: This does not seem an integral equation.

Comment: @JJacquelin I edited the question. I can plot the $g$ function for $s>T$ but I don't know how to get its closed-form.

Comment: @Jon I edited the question. Is that clearer now?

Comment: @ftor Ok, but you gave $g(s)$ explicitly in the first row of your question and it does not seem an unknown.

Comment: @Jon Indeed this $g(.)$ function is known, but only on the domain $[0,T]$. But for the domain $[T, +\infty]$, we don't know what g(.) is. We are left with just an equation in the second row that defines $g(.)$.

Comment: @ftor the integral can be performed straightforwardly and the result can be prolonged to any value greater than $T$.

Comment: @Jon For example, I don't know how to express $g(T+\epsilon)$ where $\epsilon>0$ 
 even it is small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we have to solve it iteratively. First on [T,2T] and then on larger intervals with the same procedure.

For $\epsilon\in [0,T] $ we have
$$
g(T+\epsilon) = \int_{\epsilon}^T \lambda e^{-\lambda t} g(T+\epsilon-t) dt + \int_0^\epsilon \lambda e^{-\lambda t} g(T+\epsilon-t) dt + A
$$
Since you have a explicit and nice representation for $g$ on $[0,T]$ that 
you can insert into the first integral,
the first integral can be explicitly computed, say it has the value $f(\epsilon)$. Its derivative can be also explicitly computed.
Writing $h(\epsilon) = g(T+\epsilon)$ and differentiating yields
$$
h'(\epsilon) = f'(\epsilon)+  \lambda e^{\lambda\epsilon }h(0) + \int_0^\epsilon 
\lambda e^{-\lambda t} h'(\epsilon-t) d t.
$$
Integration by parts yields
$$
h'(\epsilon) =f'(\epsilon)+  \lambda h(\epsilon) 
-\lambda \int_0^\epsilon 
\lambda e^{-\lambda t} h(\epsilon-t) dt.
$$

Inserting the first equation yields
$$
h'(\epsilon) = f'(\epsilon)
 + \lambda f(\epsilon) + \lambda A, h(0) =  g(T),
$$
so that the fundamental theorem of calculus implies
$$
g(T+\epsilon ) = h(\epsilon)= g(T) +  f(\epsilon) -f(0)  + \lambda \int_0^\epsilon f(s) d s +  \lambda A \epsilon.
$$

Comment: The only typo is $g(T+\epsilon) = g(T) + f(\epsilon) - f(0) + \lambda \int_{0}^\epsilon f(s) ds + \lambda A \epsilon$.

Comment: @ftor: I corrected it.